# Problemas no uso do sistema de cache do PHPExcel com Laravel 4.2

Tags: microsoft-excel, laravel-4, memória, cache, phpexcel

Estou tentando utilizar o sistema de cache da biblioteca **PHPExcel**, porém ainda estou obtendo estouro de memória em meu aplicativo. Necessito utilizar cache pois estou gerando relatórios com mais de **100 mil** registros em um servidor com memória limitada. Assim sendo, aumentar o uso de memória no arquivo *php.ini* não solucionaria meu problema.
Utilizo o seguinte código no construtor da classe:

```
public function __construct() {
        $templateFileName = $this->getTemplateFileName();
        $fullPathTemplate = public_path().'/Temp/'.$templateFileName.'.xlsx';

        $cacheMethod = \PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
        $cacheSettings = array(
            'memoryCacheSize' => '50MB'
        );
        if (! \PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings)) {
            die($cacheMethod . " Cache invalido " . EOL);
        }
        \Log::info("Utilizando PHPExcel com sistema de cache.");



        $objPhpReader = new \PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
        $this->phpExcelObject = $objPhpReader->load($fullPathTemplate);
}
```

Tenho a impressão que não esta habilitando o sistema de cache, o erro retornado no log do **Laravel 4.2** é o seguinte:

```
[2016-12-06 15:38:42] production.INFO: Utilizando PHPExcel com sistema de cache. [] []
[2016-12-06 15:45:29] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Out of memory (allocated 1857028096) (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes)' in D:\Projetos\Rel\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\CachedObjectStorage\PHPTemp.php:65
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Agradeço desde já a atenção de todos.

Comment: Acho, que deveria repensar o uso de **100 mil registros**, o problema é que a execução do `script` tem um certo limite e isso não é problema nem do pacote, nem do Laravel, mas, da quantidade de registros, será que não tem como gerar de outra forma ou menos registros? *acredito que o cache não vai te ajudar, porque ele vai depender da informação gerada ...*

Comment: O problema é que o relatório consolidado é um requisito do cliente, pior, esta previsto gerar relatórios do Excel com mais de 500 mil linhas, por aba.